# Adding a String in a string multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string of Hex numbers as, say

```
"010104000202000AC80627061202"
```

I want my output as

```
"01 01 04 00 02 02 00 0A C8 06 27 06 12 02"
```

I can use a for loop but is there any optimized way?

What I am doing currently is:

```
int length = line.Length/2; // Store the length of String
string outputstr = String.Empty;
for (int count = 0; count < length; count++)
  {
       outputstr += line.Substring(0, 2) + " "; //Get First two bytes and add space
       line = line.Substring(2); // Remove those two bytes
 }
```

Comment: Yes, use `StringBuilder`

Comment: Are you looking for faster or more elegant?  Your method seems pretty easy to read.

Comment: I am looking for Faster way or as I said, "Optimized way"

Comment: @SwanandPurankar: Optimized does not necessarily mean _faster_. Performance is overrated. While users doesn't even notice a difference of few milliseconds they'll notice a bug(maybe caused by too complicated code)  or an exceeded deadline for sure ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree with your statement that user will not notice the difference of miliseconds, But consider this (Assuming code is bug free) If it delays execution by 5 miliseconds and User executes code 100 times in a day, I can save him 500 mSec a day... 15 seconds a month... They cost a bomb for 15 seconds TV commercial, Think how important Every milisecond is!!  ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I believe in "Save penny (Here, time) wherever you can". But Yes, This should not create any errors! Bug free slow code is better than Buggy fast code!

Comment: @SwanandPurankar: No, he will not notice the difference. But he will notice the difference if he waits some days more for an update or a new feature. The biggest problems with "premature optimization" are that it can introduce unexpected bugs and can be a huge time waster.  Most of the time premature/micro-optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *faster* you can change to stringbuilder:

```
int length = line.Length; // Store the length of String -- see edit below
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for (int count = 0; count < length; count += 2)  // makes more sense to increment the loop by 2
{
    output.Append(line.Substring(count, 2) + " "); //Get First two bytes and add space
}
```

One way to do it using Linq is

```
string.Join(" ",                      // join the string collection created below
    line.Select((c,i) => new {c,i})   // get each character and its index
        .GroupBy(g => g.i/2)          // group in pairs
        .Select(g => new string(g.Select(ci => ci.c).ToArray()))  // convert to char arrays and merge into strings
     );
```

Or

```
string.Join(" ",
Enumerable
    .Range(0, s.Length/2)
    .Select(i => s.Substring(i*2, 2))
 )
```

Although that essentially calls `Substring` in a "loop" so it may not be the most efficient method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex:

```
string outputstr = Regex.Replace(inputstr, ".{2}", "$0 ");
```

Comment: Regex are always elegant !

Comment: Small and elegant, but not performant. I think the OP asked for a performant way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This looks simple yet performing too.

```
private static string DoThat(string input)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 2)
    {
        sb.Append(input, i, 2);
        sb.Append(" ");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I'd rather construct the StringBuilder as follows: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Math.Max(0, line.Length * 3 / 2 - 1));`, and use `sb.Append(' ');`. You also need `if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Length--;` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Because the length of your output string is known in advance, the fastest way is to allocate a `char[]` of the final size, fill it and then `return new string(myCharBuffer);`. This is also faster that the always praised `StringBuilder`. Just two allocations are needed, both of which have the perfect size, and the 2nd one is filled by `memcpy`.

Comment: Fill it means again `for` ??

Comment: Yes. If you want performance, that is what you need. Doesn't get faster than that. The more abstractions you add, the slower it gets. This is the fastest method I know of (that's safe managed code).

Comment: What makes you think that StringBuilder would be slower, if constructed with the correct length?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten because it can't possibly as fast as sequentially setting a few bytes in an array. It does more stuff. Also, care must be taken not to call Substring in the inner loop and pass substrings to StringBuilder. That would destroy performance.

Comment: Ah, but that's the thing, what Append is doing, is exactly that: setting a few bytes in an array and keeping track of where you are in that array (which is something you would have to do as well). For long strings this algorithm will be bound by memory speeds, and both will be equally fast. For short strings it won't matter. As for the Substring: of course, but that applies to both cases. See the answer by Sriram Sakthivel and my comment there.

Comment: And in fact, the fastest would be to construct a string of the correct length, and to overwrite its chars using unsafe code. More or less the same as what you have in mind, but without needing the memcpy at the end.

Comment: I agree with your thinking in general. On the other hand you'd probably call `StringBuilder Append(string value, int startIndex, int count)`. Reflector shows a lot of stuff going on. The JIT cannot be trusted to optimize this out or even inline the method. When you have this kind of overhead for every two chars, it adds up. I'm not convinced we'd be bound by memory speeds here. Sequential memory access is very fast (on the order of 10GB/sec).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you are going to loop and use string manipulation, use a Stringbuilder.

This is because a String is immutable, and while it may seem as if you are altering it, a new object is actually created each iteration and is kept in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `StringBuilder` if the string is large:

```
if(line.Length > 100)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(line.Length + line.Length/2);
    for(int i=0; i < line.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(line[i]);
        if (i % 2 == 1 && i < line.Length-1)
            sb.Append(' ');
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
// else your approach
```

Answer (score 0):

You could something like this:

```
var unformatedString = "010104000202000AC80627061202";
var formatedString = Regex.Replace(@"..", "$0 ");
```

This is definitely not faster, but alot easier to read.